# Good Architecture for Angular 2/4/5 systems

Tags: javascript, angular, architecture, frontend

I'm working on a project that uses Angular 4 as the front-end framework. My question is, what the best architecture (folders separations, modules, etc.) to use in an Angular 4 project?

I've read a lot of articles and the opinions are quite different about it. Some articles suggest various independent modules across the application, some suggest all components being children of main app module.

So if someone has worked or works on a large angular 4 project and can share the experience, architecture used and how the experience goes, I'll be very glad.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a good place for generic questions like that. Please check the FAQ on how to ask a good question. As for the question itself, you'll find the answer at the angular docs: https://angular.io/docs and other places.

Comment: this is a very [subjective question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Sorry for that. I'll delete the question.

Comment: I think this is a good question although it is generic. I didn't know how to structure my own project until I read Todd Motto's blog

Answer (score 1):

High recommend the Angular Architecture which Todd Motto introduced, you can find it here: https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-architecture.

Basically, there are 2 kinds of components: Container components and Presentational components, containers are **stateful** which means they interact with services to fetch data and update data, presentational components are **stateless** which means they do not interact with services but pass data via @Input and @Output, in this way it's easy to maintain code and it's clear on the data flow. Read more from the pasted link and hope it helps

```
index.html
app/
│    app.component.scss
│    app.component.spec.ts
│    app.component.ts
│    app.module.ts
└──  meal-planner/
   │         meal-planner.module.ts
   │         meal-planner.service.spec.ts
   │         meal-planner.service.ts
   ├── components/
   │         meal-viewer/
   │             meal-viewer.component.scss
   │             meal-viewer.component.spec.ts
   │             meal-viewer.component.ts
   │         meal-editor/
   │             meal-editor.component.scss
   │             meal-editor.component.spec.ts
   │             meal-editor.component.ts
   │         meal-recipe/
   │             meal-recipe.component.scss
   │             meal-recipe.component.spec.ts
   │             meal-recipe.component.ts
   ├── containers/
   │         meal-planner/
   │             meal-planner.component.scss
   │             meal-planner.component.spec.ts
   │             meal-planner.component.ts
   └── models/
              meal.interface.ts
              recipe.interface.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this stucture ..create 
**athentification module with its**
 1. auth-routing.modules.ts
 2. auth-component.ts
 3. auth.module.ts
Here create login component and add it in auth module

as well as **Page** also its three ts files 
here create pages component and add it in page module

share folder contain common **component** and **services**

[image]